# Samba auth against windows domain: Is /etc/nsswitch.conf required?

Tags: authentication, samba, nsswitch.conf

When I use samba to authenticate users against an existing windows domain controller, do I have to use `winbind` and add winbind to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Is there a way to do this without having to use `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?
I simply want to auth against a windows server, nothing else :-)

The main thing I want to avoid is having all domain users/groups show up in `getent passwd` or `getent group`.